# Second order differential equation with change of variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following equation:
$u''(x) + \frac{u(x)}{4x^2} = 0 $ with $u(1) = u(2) = 0$

I tried to make the following:

Let $x = e^t$ , then $ u(x) = u(e^t) = v(t) $ , which gives me:

$u'(e^t) = e^{-t} v'(t)$

$u''(e^t) = e^{-2t}(v''(t)-v'(t))$

Putting it back in the original equation, I have:

$ 4v''(t) - 4v'(t) + v(t) = 0$

But the solution is $ 4v''(t) - 4v'(t) = 0$. I can't see where I'm making a mistake.

Comment: Your solution seems correct to me. Did you try to solve it ?

Comment: With those particular boundary conditions, I imagine that $u(x)=0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$u''(x)+\frac{u(x)}{4x^2}=0 \tag 1$$
This is a degenerate case of Bessel differential equation.

Let $u(x)=x^{1/2}y(x).\quad$ Eq.$(1)$ is tranformed into 
$$xy''+y'=0$$
Which solution is :
$$y=c_1\ln|x|+c_2$$
The general solution of Eq.$(1)$ is :
$$u(x)=x^{1/2}\left(c_1\ln|x|+c_2 \right)$$
For $x\to 0$ the limit of $x^{1/2}\ln(x)$ is $0.$ Thus the condition $u(0)=0$ is satisfied.

$u'(x)=\frac{c_1\ln|x|+2c_1+c_2}{2x^{1/2}}$

For $x\to 0\quad |u'(x)|\to\infty$ except if $c_1=c_2=0.$

Thus the condition $u'(0)=0$ is satisfied only if $c_1=c_2=0.$ This is the unique solution $u(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You made no mistake. The answer provided is simply wrong. An obvious solution of the DE
$$4(v''-v')=0$$
Is $v=e^t$. Note that $x=e^t$

Is $u(x)=x$ a solution of the original equation ?
$$4x^2u''+u=0$$